# How to find a $f$ such that $F=grad \ f$?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

I need help with this problem:

> For the conservative field $F$ find a function $f$ such that $F=$ grad$f$.
>   $$F(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{x}{r},\frac{y}{r},\frac{z}{r}\right)$$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+x^2}$.

I tried to find $f$ by integrating the partial derivatives, but since $1/r$ is multiplying the whole vector, I just took it out, I'm not sure if I can do that. Like this:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=x$$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y,z)=y$$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,y,z)=z$$ thus $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{2}+g(y,z)$$ $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{y^2}{2}+h(x,z)$$ $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{z^2}{2}+k(x,y)$$ for some functions $g$, $h$, and $k$, so if $g=\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}$, $h=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}$ and $k=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}$, the function $f$ is: $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{r}(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2})=\frac{1}{2r}\cdot r^2=\frac {r}{2}$$

Am I correct? If not, how can I solve this correctly, should I integrate $x/r$, $y/r$ and $z/r$ instead?

Comment: Check your own work: what is $\nabla(r/2)$?

Comment: You are wrong in assuming that $r$ is a constant. In fact $r=r(x,y,z)= \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: I see, thanks, so I just need to integrate including $r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily check that 
$$ F(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}(x,y,z)$$ 
is conservative. In order to find a potential $f(x,y,z)$, I would typically "guess" the result.

However, one can of course also "derive" it by integration. We choose the value $f(0,0,0)= f_0$ as the integration constant. For obtaining the value $f(x,y,z)$, we choose the curve
$$ \gamma\colon t\in[0,1]\mapsto (x t,y t,z t)= (x,y,z) t\in \mathbb{R}^3\,.$$
We evaluate the line integral
$$ f(x,y,z) = \int_\gamma F(x,y,z)\cdot dr +f_0= \int_0^1 \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} dt + f_0 = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}  + f_0$$

Comment: How would you guess it? I tried to solve the problem again bu with $r$ and my three integrals and I got the same as you, all of the gave me $r$ plus some constant, so the constant mus be $0$, right?

Comment: The constant can be whatever you like. Fuction $f$ isn't uniquely defined, adding a constant does not change its gradient.

Comment: Guessing involves finding a function whose $x$ derivative is $F_1$, and so on. It is thus similar to solving an ODE.